# What is the API name of group in feeditem object?

Tags: api, feeditem

[image: What is the field name of the highlighted part?]

I have referred this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) but didn't find the field.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you posted, it looks like either the NetworkScope or Visibility fields

Comment: is it possible to run query on those fields?

Comment: Both are available for selection in a SOQL query when I had a quick look in Developer Workbench (https://workbench.developerforce.com) so yes, should be able to.